# After upgrading to MS Word 2016 the method Document_ContentControlOnExit does not fire

Tags: vba, ms-word

I was on MS Word 2007 where the macros worked fine.
After upgrading to MS Word 2016 the method Document_ContentControlOnExit does not fire.
Since I write very few MS Word macros I don’t keep up on fundamental change to the architecture.  Has something changed in MS Word 2016 that would cause the code to stop working?

The set of methods will detect a Content Control exit.  Then update all Content Controls with the same tag name with the new value.

I have put a breakpoint in Document_ContentControlOnExit.  Then made some changes to a Content Control.  Nothing.

```
Sub SetUp()  
    Set eventHandler.doc = ActiveDocument  
End Sub  
Sub Document_Close()  
    Call UpdateAllFields  
End Sub  

Private Sub Document_ContentControlOnExit(ByVal ContentControl As ContentControl, Cancel As Boolean)  
   ccTag = ContentControl.Tag  
   ccValue = ContentControl.Range.Text  
   Call updateValueInAllInstances(ccTag, ccValue)  
End Sub  

Sub updateValueInAllInstances(ccTag, ccValue)  
    Dim doc As Document  
    Dim ccs As ContentControls  
    Dim cc As ContentControl  
    Set doc = ActiveDocument  
For Each cc In doc.SelectContentControlsByTag(ccTag)  
    ' If the author of the document did not lock the contents, then perform a auto update.  
    If cc.LockContents Then  
        Respose = MsgBox("The author of this cookbook has deliberately designed this specific content control to not be editable.", 0, "Content Control is not editable", "", 1000)  
    Else  
        cc.Range.Text = ccValue  
    End If  
Next cc  
End Sub  

Sub UpdateAllFields()  
    Dim objStory As Range  
    Dim objTOC As TableOfContents  
    Dim objTOA As TableOfAuthorities  
    Dim objTOF As TableOfFigures  
    Dim objIndex As Index  

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False  
    Application.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone  

    For Each objStory In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges  
        UpdateFieldsInStory objStory  

        While Not (objStory.NextStoryRange Is Nothing)  
            Set objStory = objStory.NextStoryRange  
            UpdateFieldsInStory objStory  
        Wend  
    Next  

    For Each objTOC In ActiveDocument.TablesOfContents
        objTOC.Update  
    Next  

    For Each objTOA In ActiveDocument.TablesOfAuthorities
        objTOA.Update  
    Next  

    For Each objTOF In ActiveDocument.TablesOfFigures
        objTOF.Update  
    Next  

    For Each objIndex In ActiveDocument.Indexes
        objIndex.Update  
    Next  

    Application.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsAll  
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub  
Private Sub UpdateFieldsInStory(iobjStory As Range)  
    Dim objShape As Shape  

    With iobjStory
        .Fields.Update

        Select Case .StoryType
            Case wdMainTextStory, wdPrimaryHeaderStory, _
              wdPrimaryFooterStory, wdEvenPagesHeaderStory, _
              wdEvenPagesFooterStory, wdFirstPageHeaderStory, _
              wdFirstPageFooterStory

                For Each objShape In .ShapeRange
                    With objShape.TextFrame
                        If .HasText Then .TextRange.Fields.Update
                    End With
                Next
        End Select
    End With
End Sub
```

I was hoping the code was not so out of date that it would keep working.

Comment: Actually, this hasn't changed. But if all the code you show is in the same code module then the event cannot work (and should not have worked in 2007). Content control events *must be* in the `ThisDocument` module.

Answer (score 0):

This mistake was what Cindy Meister pointed out.  When I copied the macro code from the old to the new template I failed to notice the location in the Visual Basic Editor.  Once the code was in the correct place it worked.

[image]